# Circle vector inside another one

Tags: android, xml, svg, vector, android-vectordrawable

I need to put inside a circle shape another one, but i can't do it. I created the first shape (a circle with 2 lines. One on top, the other on bottom) and i need to put a simple circle shape inside of it. Maybe with a bit of padding between the shapes. That's the code that i have done so far :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:viewportHeight="24">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#62a35d"
        android:pathData="M17,12C17,14.42 15.28,16.44 13,16.9V21H11V16.9C8.72,16.44 7,14.42 7,12C7,9.58 8.72,7.56 11,7.1V3H13V7.1C15.28,7.56 17,9.58 17,12M12,9A3,3 0 0,0 9,12A3,3 0 0,0 12,15A3,3 0 0,0 15,12A3,3 0 0,0 12,9Z" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#62a35d"
        android:pathData="M22,32
        A10,10 0 1,1 42,32
        A10,10 0 1,1 22,32 Z" />
</vector>
```

The second shape is currently not visible. It become visible if i change the `android:viewportWidth` and `android:viewportHeight` from 24 to 64. But it's not what i have to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per your requirement here is a vector drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="640dp"
    android:height="640dp"
    android:viewportWidth="640"
    android:viewportHeight="640">

    <path
        android:fillColor="#582370"
        android:strokeWidth="1"
        android:pathData="M465.28 323.25C465.28 403.15 400.18 468.02 320 468.02C239.82 468.02 174.72 403.15 174.72 323.25C174.72 243.35 239.82 178.49 320 178.49C400.18 178.49 465.28 243.35 465.28 323.25Z" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#e1db5f"
        android:strokeWidth="1"
        android:pathData="M428.57 322.19C429.14 380.15 380.95 427.68 321.02 428.27C261.1 428.85 211.99 382.27 211.43 324.31C210.86 266.35 259.05 218.83 318.98 218.24C378.9 217.66 428.01 264.24 428.57 322.19Z" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#582370"
        android:strokeWidth="1"
        android:pathData="M300.12 20.46L339.88 20.46L339.88 189.7L300.12 189.7L300.12 20.46Z" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#582370"
        android:strokeWidth="1"
        android:pathData="M300.12 450.3L339.88 450.3L339.88 619.54L300.12 619.54L300.12 450.3Z" />
</vector>
```

and if you need circle into a circle

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:width="640dp"
    android:height="640dp"
    android:viewportWidth="640"
    android:viewportHeight="640">

    <path
        android:fillColor="#582370"
        android:strokeWidth="1"
        android:pathData="M483.63 266.48C483.63 346.38 418.53 411.24 338.35 411.24C258.17 411.24 193.07 346.38 193.07 266.48C193.07 186.58 258.17 121.71 338.35 121.71C418.53 121.71 483.63 186.58 483.63 266.48Z" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#e1db5f"
        android:strokeWidth="1"
        android:pathData="M449.02 265.42C449.58 323.38 401.39 370.9 341.47 371.49C281.55 372.07 232.44 325.49 231.87 267.54C231.31 209.58 279.5 162.05 339.42 161.46C399.34 160.88 448.45 207.46 449.02 265.42Z" />
</vector>
```

**UPDATED**: add padding or add the third circle into vector image (padding is not possible so I add another circle into the image so you can change color as you need)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:width="24dp"
android:height="24dp"
android:viewportWidth="24.0"
android:viewportHeight="24.0">

<path
    android:fillColor="#5ba1fd"
    android:strokeWidth="1"
    android:pathData="M19.5 12.07C19.5 16.23 16.14 19.61 12 19.61C7.86 19.61 4.5 16.23 4.5 12.07C4.5 7.9 7.86 4.53 12 4.53C16.14 4.53 19.5 7.9 19.5 12.07Z" />
<path
    android:fillColor="#ffffff"
    android:strokeWidth="1"
    android:pathData="M18.11 12.07C18.11 15.4 15.42 18.1 12.11 18.1C8.79 18.1 6.11 15.4 6.11 12.07C6.11 8.74 8.79 6.03 12.11 6.03C15.42 6.03 18.11 8.74 18.11 12.07Z" />
<path
    android:fillColor="#832727"
    android:strokeWidth="1"
    android:pathData="M17.61 11.93C17.66 14.98 15.23 17.52 12.2 17.6C9.16 17.67 6.66 15.26 6.62 12.21C6.57 9.15 9 6.61 12.03 6.54C15.07 6.46 17.57 8.88 17.61 11.93Z" />
<path
    android:fillColor="#5ba1fd"
    android:strokeWidth="1"
    android:pathData="M10.5 0L13.5 0L13.5 4.7L10.5 4.7L10.5 0Z" />
<path
    android:fillColor="#5ba1fd"
    android:strokeWidth="1"
    android:pathData="M10.5 19.3L13.5 19.3L13.5 24L10.5 24L10.5 19.3Z" /></vector>
```

Comment: Just one another thing, is it possible do the same but with viewportWidth 24 instead 640? And viewportHeight too of course

Comment: And put some padding between 2 circles

Comment: can you please share image which you need

Comment: Basically, starting from the first code you wrote, I just need some space between the first and the second shape.the yellow circle should be inside the purple one but with some space around it. Just to separate the two shape

Comment: That's perfect! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if you need more help let me know :

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape
        android:shape="oval">
        <solid
            android:color="#00fff"/>
        <padding
            android:bottom="30dp"
            android:left="30dp"
            android:right="30dp"
            android:top="30dp"/>
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#ffffff"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape
        android:shape="oval">
        <solid
            android:color="#00666666"/>

        <size
            android:width="120dp"
            android:height="120dp"/>
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#25242b"/>
    </shape>

</item>
```